# Merging files into one also adding a new line between each file

Tags: files, find

I'm using

```
find . -type f \( -name "*.js" ! -name "*-min*" \) -exec cat {} \; > all.js
```

to merge files together. Unfortunately I don't get a new line after each file but it ends and the new file starts on the same line.

How can I add a newline between each file?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The script below will do the task

```
find . -type f \( -name "*.js" ! -name "*-min*" \) | while IFS= read -r line
do
   cat "$line"
   echo
done >all.js
```

Comment: Perfect! Will accept in 3 min ;)

Answer (score 6):

If you want to systematically add a newline after each file:

```
find . -type f \( -name "*.js" ! -name "*-min*" \) \
     -exec cat {} \; -exec echo \; > all.js
```

or

```
find . -type f \( -name "*.js" ! -name "*-min*" \) \
     -exec sh -c 'for x; do cat "$x"; echo; done' _ {} + >all.js
```

If you want to add a newline at the end of each file that doesn't end with a newline:

```
find . -type f \( -name "*.js" ! -name "*-min*" \) \
     -exec awk '1' {} + > all.js
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also do this way:

```
find source/path -name *.js | xargs cat > all.js
```

---